# Override Drag and drop for Shell Extension

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, shell-extensions

I am working on a ShellExtension code in C++. I am creating a Virtual Drive. Which represents a repository somewhere in the Network. What I want now is to enable Drag-Drop functionality to this Drive. I want to enable user to drag the file to that Virtual Drive and then I must be able to Grab that event, so that I can perform my custom operation. I am not able to find any of such Event or Interface so far. I tried using `IDragAndDrop` interface, but its rgs files were not registering properly. Is there any way out?

Comment: You should probably tell us which OS you're talking about, I assume it's windows?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you ask for is covered in MSDN's documentation:

[Handling Shell Data Transfer Scenarios](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776904.aspx)

[Implementing the Basic Folder Object Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776815.aspx) (in particular, IShellFolder::GetUIObjectOf() can return an IDataObject or IDropTarget interface)

[Creating Drop Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776846.aspx)