# Drag anything onto the desktop

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, drag-and-drop, desktop

Is there a way that we can drag text or images onto the desktop itself from within another application?

Say for example there is some text in my app, and the user wants to drag it right onto the desktop, and be able to move it around and edit it right on the desktop... Would this be possible at all?

Thank you :)

I mainly use C# and C++. But if I have to use another language or learn another language for this, then I'm prepared to do so.

Comment: Sorry, edit it on the desktop? In what way? Do you mean the plain text (word wrapped?) should just appear on top of their desktop background/icons, and be editable? Does this have to persist - i.e. are you looking for a widget style thing?

Comment: Not a widget, UNless, you can drag it around wherever you like and not be constricted in anyway. And yeah, wordwrap would have to be in there. And it should appear ontop of other icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at writing Shell Extensions.  Here's an article to get you started

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx

Here's another questions that has some relevant answers

[Override Drag and drop for Shell Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177384/override-drag-and-drop-for-shell-extension)